# Inline parsing of IObservable<byte>

Tags: system.reactive

I have an observable query that produces an `IObservable<byte>` from a stream that I want to parse inline. I want to be able to use different strategies depending on the data source to parse discrete messages from this sequence. Bear in mind I am still on the upward learning curve of RX. I have come up with a solution, but am unsure if there is a way to accomplish this using out-of-the-box operators.

First, I wrote the following extension method to IObservable:

```
    public static IObservable<IList<T>> Parse<T>(
        this IObservable<T> source,
        Func<IObservable<T>, IObservable<IList<T>>> parsingFunction)
    {
        return parsingFunction(source);
    }
```

This allows me to specify the message framing strategy in use by a particular data source. One data source might be delimited by one or more bytes while another might be delimited by both start and stop block patterns while another might use a length prefixing strategy. So here is an example of the Delimited strategy that I have defined:

```
public static class MessageParsingFunctions
{

    public static Func<IObservable<T>, IObservable<IList<T>>> Delimited<T>(T[] delimiter)
    {
        if (delimiter == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("delimiter");
        if (delimiter.Length < 1) throw new ArgumentException("delimiter must contain at least one element.");

        Func<IObservable<T>, IObservable<IList<T>>> parser =
            (source) =>
            {
                var shared = source.Publish().RefCount();

                var windowOpen = shared.Buffer(delimiter.Length, 1)
                    .Where(buffer => buffer.SequenceEqual(delimiter))
                    .Publish()
                    .RefCount();

                return shared.Buffer(windowOpen)
                    .Select(bytes =>
                        bytes
                        .Take(bytes.Count - delimiter.Length)
                        .ToList());

            };

        return parser;
    }
}
```

So ultimately, as an example, I can use the code in the following fashion to parse discrete messages from the sequence any time the byte pattern for the string `'<EOF>'` is encountered in the sequence:

```
var messages = ...operators that surface an IObservable<byte>
    .Parse(MessageParsingFunctions.Delimited(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<EOF>")))
    ...further operators to package discrete messages along with additional metadata
```

Questions:

1. Is there a more straight-forward way to accomplish this using just out of the box operators?
2. If not, would it be preferable to just define the different parsing functions (i.e. ParseDelimited, ParseLengthPrefixed, etc.) as local extensions instead of having a more generic Parse extension method that accepts a parsing function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1.  Not really.  2. That's really just an opinion on API design.  My personal answer (which is somewhat in line with the design of Rx) is "why not both?"  generic `Parse` so that a developer can easily extend with new selectors, and more specific predefined extensions as a library of ready to use parsers.

Comment: Honestly, at first glance, you could do far worse than the solution you've already posted; any "answer" is going to end up being a sort of `Func<IObservable,Chunk>` construct, where you algorithmically decide when to publish a chunk based on stream context. When I'm not on my phone I'll try to come up with an alternative just for comparison purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Rxx Parsers](https://rxx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Parsers&referringTitle=Documentation).  Here's a [related lab](https://rxx.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Testing/Rxx.Labs/Parsers/Reactive/BinaryFileLab.cs).  For example:

```
IObservable<byte> bytes = ...;

var parsed = bytes.ParseBinary(parser =>
  from next in parser
  let magicNumber = parser.String(Encoding.UTF8, 3).Where(value => value == "RXX")
  let header = from headerLength in parser.Int32
               from header in next.Exactly(headerLength)
               from headerAsString in header.Aggregate(string.Empty, (s, b) => s + " " + b)
               select headerAsString
  let message = parser.String(Encoding.UTF8)
  let entry = from length in parser.Int32
              from data in next.Exactly(length)
              from value in data.Aggregate(string.Empty, (s, b) => s + " " + b)
              select value
  let entries = from count in parser.Int32
                from entries in entry.Exactly(count).ToList()
                select entries
  select from _ in magicNumber.Required("The file's magic number is invalid.")
         from h in header.Required("The file's header is invalid.")
         from m in message.Required("The file's message is invalid.")
         from e in entries.Required("The file's data is invalid.")
         select new
         {
           Header = h,
           Message = m,
           Entries = e.Aggregate(string.Empty, (acc, cur) => acc + cur + Environment.NewLine)
         });
```